# Deallocating Dynamic 2D Array with Template

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

I am having an error in my C++ application that I am having trouble debugging.  I have looked online, and I appear to be doing all of my allocation/deallocation the correct way.  Here is my code:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
private:
   int _rows;
   int _cols;
   T** _matrix;
public:
   Matrix(int r, int c);
   ~Matrix();
   T GetValue(int r, int c);
};

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int r, int c)
{
   _rows = r;
   _cols = c;

   _matrix = new T*[_rows];
   for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
      _matrix[i] = new T[_cols];

   for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j < _cols; j++)
         _matrix[i][j] = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
      delete [] _matrix[i];
   delete [] _matrix;
}

template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::GetValue(int r, int c)
{
   if(r < 0 || r >= _rows || c < 0 || c > _cols)
   {
      throw -1;
      return NULL;
   }

   return _matrix[r][c];
}
```

And my client code...

```
int main()
{
   Matrix<int> myMatrix(3, 3);
   myMatrix.GetValue(1, 1);
   // myMatrix.~Matrix();  // Don't do this anymore
}
```

As soon as the variable "myMatrix" goes out of scope, I get this error:

Unhandled exception at 0x103159da (msvcr1000d.dll)...Access violation reading location 0xfeeefee2.
And I am brought to the file "dbgdel.cpp"
_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));

Please help!

---

EDIT:

Okay, I neglected to give some information.  Please see below:

I have an additional method called "T Dot(Matrix)"  I've also got two methods called "Columns()" and "Rows()" which are just getters for _cols and _rows. And a method called "SetValue(int r, int c, T value)" which sets `_matrix[r][c] = value`. I don't think showing the implementation is necessary for these.

```
template <typename T>
T Matrix<T>::Dot(Matrix<T> m)
{
   if(_cols > 1 || m.Columns() > 1 || _rows != m.Rows())
   {
      throw -1;
      return NULL;
   }

   T value = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < _rows; i++)
   {
      value += _matrix[i][0] * m.GetValue(i, 0);
   }
   return value; // Whoops, this was here, just forgot to type it
}
```

And the client...

```
int main()
{
   Matrix<int> intM1(3, 1);
   Matrix<int> intM2(3, 1);

   intM1.SetValue(0, 0, 1);
   intM1.SetValue(1, 0, 1);
   intM1.SetValue(2, 0, 1);
   intM2.SetValue(0, 0, 1);
   intM2.SetValue(1, 0, 1);
   intM2.SetValue(2, 0, 1);

   std::cout << intM1.Dot(intM2) << endl;
}
```

This generates the same error as above, but only when the "Dot()" function is called.

Comment: Have you tried removing myMatrix.~Matrix() from your main function?  The destructor is called automatically once the object goes out of scope, you shouldn't be calling it explicitly.

Comment: @Connman. Thanks, I knew the destructor was called automatically but I put it in there as a test.  I could have sworn I was getting errors even when I didn't have it in there, but of course they have disappeared now that I've asked this question.  I am going to try to reproduce what I had a few hours ago.

Comment: @Eric, don't put such misleading code in your question, if you are not using it. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your edit, the issue here is still the lack of a copy constructor and assignment operator (see my answer to your last question).  The problem is that when you pass the `Matrix` by value into a function, the copy constructor is invoked to make the copy, but since you haven't defined one C++ will use the default copy constructor, which just makes a shallow copy.  Consequently, you'll end up getting a new `Matrix` that shares a pointer to the same elements as the old `Matrix`.  When this new `Matrix` goes out of scope, its destructor will fire, cleaning up the array used by the other `Matrix`.  When the original `Matrix` then goes out of scope and is cleaned up, it will try to delete an already-deleted array, causing the crash.

To fix this, you need to implement a copy constructor and assignment operator that correctly duplicate the resources.  There's a rule-of-thumb called the Rule of Three that says that if you have a destructor, you also need a copy constructor and assignment operator to prevent these sorts of bugs.  Try implementing these missing functions and see if the problem clears up.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent explanation and direction for solving this problem. Sorry for the confusion earlier.

Comment: While this is exactly right, you may want to consider whether you really want to be passing a copy of the matrix as an argument to `Dot`. I would expect this to be a `const` reference: `T Matrix<T>::Dot(Matrix<T> const& m) // etc`. This way you don't copy the whole matrix each time you call `Dot`.

Comment: @Darren Engwirda- Absolutely.  Still, the missing copy functions should be taken care of as soon as possible to prevent bugs like this from showing up in seemingly valid code.

Comment: @Darren Engwirda: Thanks, I was actually thinking about that a few minutes ago.  I will most likely make it a const.  However, I was not aware of the "Rule of Three," so I will definitely be reading up about that.  If anyone happens to be reading this, here is the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Answer (score 3):

Don't call the destructor explicitly, you've allocated `myMatrix` on the stack, so the `dtor` will automatically be called when the variable goes out of scope, i.e. when `main()` returns.

Comment: @Templatetypedef: Yup, the *only* place I can think where you would call the `dtor` explicitly is to clean up objects created using placement `new`...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind comments.  Please see my edit and provide additional comments if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

Here is the error:

```
T Matrix<T>::Dot(Matrix<T> m);
```

This function should return `T` and it's not returning in the end !! Put,

```
return value;
```

And it should be solved. Also there are some suggestions: You are passing `Matrix<T> m;` by value which is error prone. Because both the copied `m` and original `intM2` will point to same `_matrix`. So when `m` goes out of scope it will `delete[]` everything. When `intM2` goes out of scope, it will **again delete the same memory**. Which again a crash.

So you should always specify copy constructor (either as `private` or with proper copying code). As of now change the definition to,

```
T Matrix<T>::Dot(Matrix<T> &m); // pass `m` by reference
```

This will resolve all your errors. (You can choose to pass by `const Matrix<T> &m` also, for that you may have to change `GetValue () const`.)

Comment: Thanks.  I feel bad because I accidentally asked the wrong question. Could you please read my edit and provide your expertise?